# Conditionally change a new field's value based on another field in python during a dictionary loop

Tags: python, pandas

so I have a dictionary with a bunch of keys and data frames

```
df_dict = {'grade_1_math': grade_1_class_2029,
'grade_2_eng': grade_2_class_2029,
'grade_3_math': grade_3_class_2029,
'grade_4_eng': grade_4_class_2029,
'grade_5_math': grade_5_class_2029}
```

every data frame has a string column called 'Course' that either will or won't have the word 'math' in it

I am trying to create a new column called 'Subject' which evaluates 'Course' and fills itself with either Mathematics or Language Arts

```
for key, val in df_dict.items():
  val['Subject'] = np.where('math' in val['Course'], 'Language Arts', 'Mathematics')
```

but it comes out wrong every time. Am I doing something wrong? I would like to keep this in a dictionary loop since I do many other things as well.

@laurent asked for before and after of grade_1_class_2029.head().to_dict()

Before:

```
{'Course': {0: 'English 10',
  1: 'English 10',
  2: 'English 10',
  3: 'English 10',
  4: 'English 10'},
 'Current Grade Level': {0: '12', 1: '12', 2: '12', 3: '11', 4: '12'},
 'F1 Percent': {0: <NA>, 1: <NA>, 2: <NA>, 3: <NA>, 4: <NA>},
 'Stored Grade Level': {0: '10', 1: '10', 2: '10', 3: '10', 4: '10'},
 'Student_ID': {0: '20741', 1: '20722', 2: '20583', 3: '21111', 4: '20725'},
 'Y1 Percent': {0: '81.2', 1: '83', 2: '79.5', 3: '59.6', 4: '88.3'}}
```

After:

```
{'Course': {0: 'English 10',
  1: 'English 10',
  2: 'English 10',
  3: 'English 10',
  4: 'English 10'},
 'Current Grade Level': {0: '12', 1: '12', 2: '12', 3: '11', 4: '12'},
 'F1 Percent': {0: <NA>, 1: <NA>, 2: <NA>, 3: <NA>, 4: <NA>},
 'Stored Grade Level': {0: '10', 1: '10', 2: '10', 3: '10', 4: '10'},
 'Student_ID': {0: '20741', 1: '20722', 2: '20583', 3: '21111', 4: '20725'},
 'Subject': {0: 'Mathematics',
  1: 'Mathematics',
  2: 'Mathematics',
  3: 'Mathematics',
  4: 'Mathematics'},
 'Y1 Percent': {0: '81.2', 1: '83', 2: '79.5', 3: '59.6', 4: '88.3'}}
```

Comment: Hi, could you show the output of `grade_1_class_2029.head().to_dict()` before and after the loop?

Comment: @Laurent I have added it to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause of the problem:**

`val['Course']` is a pandas series so the condition `math in va['Course']` will always evaluate to `False` thus in the `np.where` clause the choice `Mathematics` is always selected.

**How to fix the problem?**

In order to fix the problem, you have to check the occurrence of word `math` in every string from the column `Course` and then use `np.where` to decide which choice should get selected for the corresponding  string

```
for key, val in df_dict.items():
    mask = val['Course'].str.contains('math', case=False)
    val['Subject'] = np.where(mask, 'Mathematics', 'Language Arts')
```

Result for `grade_1_class_2029`

```
>>> grade_1_class_2029

       Course Current Grade Level  F1 Percent Stored Grade Level Student_ID Y1 Percent        Subject
0  English 10                  12         NaN                 10      20741       81.2  Language Arts
1  English 10                  12         NaN                 10      20722         83  Language Arts
2  English 10                  12         NaN                 10      20583       79.5  Language Arts
3  English 10                  11         NaN                 10      21111       59.6  Language Arts
4  English 10                  12         NaN                 10      20725       88.3  Language Arts
```

---